# How do I gain permission to move and see files in in an Ubuntu installation from a live USB?

Tags: permissions, live-usb, root

I want to reinstall from a live USB but I have to get out pictures and music first. I booted from a live USB and get the errors

[image: This is the folder where my pictures are]

[image: When I try to open it I get this error.]

Answer (score 1):

Root is the owner of the mountpoint, and you (anonymous user of live session) have no permission there. You can gain elevated permissions by using `sudo`. I usually do this task with the cp command, but to use the file browser to move the files, open a terminal by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo -i
nautilus
```

Find the files you want and move/copy them to the desired location

When done, close the Nautilus window and type `exit` in the terminal to drop privileges.

Answer (score 0):

How did you mount that USB storage drive? 
you can always use the terminal, login as root, then copy the files.

```
sudo su
cp -rav /your/old/photos/folder /new_location
```

Hope that helps!